# How can I view logs for previous deployed versions of my Google Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a bunch of logs in the Stackdriver Logging console for a Google Cloud Function called 'Daily_ETL_Job'. I edit the code and redeploy this function, keeping the same name. Once the redeployment succeeds, I can no longer view the previous versions' logs in the Logging console. I just see a blank screen with no logs at all.

Is there some other way to view these prior deployment invocation logs?

Comment: I have reproduced the use case scenario and it worked for me. I logged "Message 01" and the changed to log "Message 02" and redeployed through Cloud Console. Then changed the code to log "Message 03" and redeployed with gcloud command. However all 3 messages are visible in the Stackdriver logging page, no matter how I redeploy the Cloud Function with the same name. Please share reproduction steps and the configuration of your Cloud Function